# use after_stat() or stat_summary() with both x and y values

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to make a histogram that shows a vertical line at the mean of `x`, and also has a text label of the mean next to the line, where the `y` value of the text label is 5% less than the largest `count` value.

Here's an illustration where the aesthetic information for the label is hardcoded:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 30) +
  stat_summary(aes(xintercept = after_stat(x), y = 0), fun = mean, geom = "vline",
               orientation = "y") +
  geom_text(x = 20.1, y = 4.75, # want to replace harcoded values here
            label = "mean: 20.1", # and here
            hjust = -0.4)
```

[image]

I'm making a large number of such histograms, so I don't want to hardcode these values. I'd also prefer not to have to calculate them manually from `mtcars`; I'd like to just let `ggplot` do the binning and related calculations for me, and access this information with the `ggplot` API. I've got this working above for the `vline`, which only operates in a single dimensions, but I can't seem to find the right syntax for a `geom` with an `aes` that uses multiple `stat`s.

The closest I've come with `stat_summary()`, which still hardcodes `y`:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 30) +
  stat_summary(aes(xintercept = after_stat(x), y = 0), fun = mean, geom = "vline",
               orientation = "y") +
  stat_summary(aes(y = 4.75, # still hardcoded
                   label = paste("mean:", round(after_stat(x), 1))), 
               fun = mean, geom = "text",
               hjust = -0.4,
               orientation = "y")
```

[image]

Closest I've come with `geom_text()`, but which still hardcodes `x` and also gets an incorrect `max(count)` value:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 30) +
  stat_summary(aes(xintercept = after_stat(x), y = 0), fun = mean, geom = "vline",
               orientation = "y") +
  geom_text(aes(
      x = 20.1, # still hardcoded
      y = after_stat(max(count)),
      label = paste('mean:', round(after_stat(max(count)), 1))
    ),
    stat = "count")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this would be to add a column representing the mean to your data, and then plot. This would be very easy to wrap in a function and perform many times.

I added a column `x` that contains the `mean` of the desired field. Then I map `max(x)` to the `x` and `label` fields of `geom_text`.

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(x = mean(mpg)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg)) +
    geom_histogram(bins = 30) +
    stat_summary(aes(xintercept = after_stat(x), y = 0), fun = mean, geom = "vline",
                 orientation = "y") +
    geom_text(aes(
      x = max(x),
      y = after_stat(max(count)),
      label = paste('mean:', round(after_stat(max(x)), 1))
    ),
    stat = "count")
```

Comment: This answer still gets the wrong value for `max(count)`, showing the label at 32 when it should be around 5.

Comment: I'd also like to avoid operating on `mtcars` before passing it to `ggplot`. That's what I'd do in a hurry, but I know there's got to be a way to do this with `ggplot` tools, and part of what I'm hoping to gain here is a better understanding of `after_stat()` and related functions.

Comment: What value are you expecting for `max(count)` in this scenario?

Comment: 5, because that's the highest `count` obtained from `geom_histogram()`, which you can see in my first plot.